# как зная длину и две точки найти конец отрезка?

Tags: c++

первая точка(A) это один из концов отрезка, вторая точка(C) просто лежит на данном отрезке. Известна длина АB(B-искомая точка)

Comment: А математика на этот счёт что говорит?

Comment: я не нашёл просто похожую задачу, вот и спросил

Comment: Просьба приложить скриншот наглядно показывающий что именно нужно найти. Так как не понятно какая именно длина известна (от 1 точки до ?) и что нужно найти ?

Comment: попробуй искать не похожую задачу, а формулу, которую можно применить. Не к каждой проблеме есть похожая задача. Хотя и похожих задач тут миллиард начиная с задачника по геометрии.

Comment: Уравнение прямой y=kx+b, ваша задача найти коэффициенты k, b

Comment: Теорема Пифагора и подобие треугольников Вам в руки

Answer (score 3):

***B = A + (C - A)(∥A - B∥ / ∥C - A∥)***, где ***A***, ***C*** и ***∥A - B∥*** считаются известным.

Comment: Вы не указали, что это вектора. Или и так понятно?

Comment: И так понятно. ***A***, ***B*** и ***C*** указаны как точки (читай вектора) в условии задачи. Значки нормы - тоже намёк. С другой стороны эта алгебра точно также работает и на числах. :)

Answer (score 0):

Уравнение прямой: [image: ax+by=c].

Оно приводится к виду [image], если a != 0, что нужно проверить отдельно.

Составляем такие уравнения для двух точек и получаем коэффициенты b' и c'.

Уравнение длины отрезка: [image]

Получаем [image]

[image]

[image]

Из этого уравнения получаем y для точки B, а затем по первому уравнению получаем x

Comment: Уравнение прямой не нужно, тем более, оно не всегда работает. Отношение разностей координат равно отношению длин отрезков - этого достаточно

Comment: Уж очень сложное решение простейшей задачи.